# Setting "checked" using a non specific id in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to checked a checkbox using the id. I know we can specifically set the id like this

```
$('#myDiv input[id="001"]').prop('checked', true);
```

However, I am looping through my id from database and thus cannot specifically set an id to it. Is there anyway on doing this?

Comment: How and where do you fetch ids from db?

Comment: I'm obtaining the id right before I try to checked the checkbox by the id

Comment: Kindly share irrelevant code for ids.

Comment: It the element with id 001 existing ? You shoud use # for id and a prefix for your item and suffix with property like id="beer1Checkbox" and access it with only #beer1Checkbox , the id must be unique. All data about item should be set using data, like data-id="1" data-name="Best beer ever" and got using data("id") and data("name").
This is not a specific solution but this may help you.

Comment: hey..thanks all..i've decided to use the normal js document.getElementById().checked = true; instead.

Comment: Just a note, an id SHOULD start with a letter for html 4 compatibility. Note also that an elements id must be unique however, the specification does not preclude an element from having multiple id's if one is set via an alternative method such as through code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').find("#001"]').prop('checked', true);
```

or simply `$("#001"]').prop('checked', true);`

or if you do not know the ID use an input type:

```
$('#myDiv').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
```